# Adding End of year balance for year each on Pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I am putting together a report about yearly expenses which keeps a running balance and I would like to show the end of year balance, with yearly expenses and debits for each year in a pivot table. I am able to add the expenses and debits for each year, since that is only taking the sum for each year. But how do i show the end of year balance for each year? So for example, I would want the value $383,728.59 shown for 2017 Balance and 2018 $435,061.29. Is this possible to do?

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: See screenshot]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

- create a calculated Field `=Received - Paid` and Name it `Balance`
- Add the `Balance` Field to the `Values` area
- Click on the down arrow next to Balance for Value Field Settings
- Summarize Values by `Sum`
- Show Values as `Running Total in Years`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a Calculated Field, select PivotTable and go to PivotTable Analyze- Fields, Items & Sets- Calculated Field- add the formula:

```
=Received -Paid
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Lee, thanks for the tip. But this seems to only have worked for the "2017". It doesnt seem to work for the other years because it only subtracts Received-Paid without taking into account the balance from the previous year.